# Potential for sodium aluminosilicate to cause aluminium toxicity

Tags: toxicity

Being an aluminium-based compound, is it conceivable that anticaking agent (554) could cause acute aluminium toxicity in excessive quantities?

Apparently 0.3% of aluminium is absorbed by the GI tract (perhaps this is different for aluminium based compounds?), 95% of which becomes bound to transport proteins and eliminated renally. If the amount exceeds what the body can excrete, the excess is deposited in tissues such as bone, brain, liver, heart, muscle, and spleen. The symptoms of aluminium toxicity include altered mental status, muscle weakness, and bone pain.

What amount of sodium aluminosilicate in an acute ingestion would be required to cause a toxic effect in a healthy individual with normal renal function?
Is there any data on the bioavailability of Al from the compound?

Comment: Welcome to HealthSE, thelastquagga! This is currently a bit unclear ("reasonable amount"?) Please expand a bit on what your previous research revealed and edit the question with the [help](https://health.stackexchange.com/help) of [how to ask](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).